# how to get data with DATE only in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

in `approve_date` I have date stored in this form `2021-04-28 20:03:00` and i want to fetch all the record from passing `2021-04-28` so i tried this piece of code

```
Order::whereDate('approve_date' , 2021-04-28)->get()->sum('subtotal');
```

but the problem is i am getting 0 and in db subtotal(sum) is 700 of 3 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
Order::whereDate('approve_date', '=', new Carbon('2021-04-28'))->get()->sum('subtotal')
```

I recomend to use DateTime object or Carbon.

PS don't forget to use use Carbon\Carbon;

Answer (score 0):

Because the date format u stored in database is 2021-04-28 20:03:00 format ,

To fetch the record with only YYYY-M-D , you first need to parse the DATE to

Order::whereDate('DATE(approve_date)' , 2021-04-28)->get()->sum('subtotal');

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE(approve_date)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where date(`DATE(approve_date)`) = 1989) getting thi serror

Comment: for this to work you will have to make a raw statement